# CSS Styling of Textarea & Select - doesn't work with previous explenations

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to increase the `font-size` in my `input` and `textarea` fields using a custom CSS sheet.

Changing the `font-size` of the `input` fields worked fine, but the `textarea` just doesn't let me resize it's `font-size`.

I also have bootstrap included, so I was wondering if my CSS sheet may be getting overwritten by the `bootstrap.css`. But I included my CSS Link after the bootstrap link in my `head` and also put the `texarea` styling at the very end of my CSS, so it should be the last one that is read.

Also I thought maybe all the bootstrap-classes that I call in the `div`, `form`, etc. around the `textarea` change the `font-size`, so I tried a `textarea` outside of the `div` elements and `form`, but the size didn't change.

https://jsfiddle.net/2nko48bL/1/

take a look at how the form looks right nowL:
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- THE IMPORTANT FORM: -->
<form >
    <!-- INPUT WITHOUT BOOTSTRAP CLASSES -> Increasing the font works fine-->
    <div>
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <!-- TEXTAREA WITHOUT BOOTSTRAP CLASSES -> Increasing the font doesn't work -->
    <div>
      <label >Longer Description</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- TEXTAREA WITH BOOTSTRAP CLASSES -> Increasing the font doesn't work -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="longerDescription" class="control-label col-sm-4">Longer Description</label>
      <div class="col">
        <textarea id="longerDescription" class="form-control" th:field="*{description}" required="required"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- INPUT WITH BOOTSTRAP CLASSES -> Increasing the font works fine again -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="contact" class="control-label col-sm-4">Contact</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="contact" class="form-control" th:field="*{contact}" required="required"/>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
<!-- TEXTAREA COMPLETELY OUTSIDE DIV AND FORM -> Increasing the font doesn't work -->
<label >Longer Description</label>
<textarea></textarea>

</body>
</html> 

input[type=text] {
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 200%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 300%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did

```
textarea 
{
  font-size: 200% !important;
}
```

and it worked fine. The `.form-control{font-size: 1rem}` of bootstrap was overwriting your css. Adding **!important** worked.

PS: If you think that some other library is maybe overwriting your css. Try to inspect and in Styles look out for the properties that are applied to your element by external libraries.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that `!important` tag ;)

Comment: oh god and thanks for the tip with the inspector, I just found another mistake much quicker with that haha